# what's the resuts of GetSkeletonJointOrientation()

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all. I have a problem about this function. I got a 3x3 matrix for every joint using this function, but i don't know which frame this orientation respect to.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9313/what%27s-the-resuts-of-getskeletonjointorientation()/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You will get 3 Vektors, representing the 3 Achses of the Joint, relative to base coord. system, which is x from Left to right, y from bottom to top and z from near to far...

The conventions can Be read in the xnTypes header in your Ni Code....

Cheers
Thorsten

---

Originally posted by [Thorsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/306/thorsten/) with karma: 61 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-03-30**:
Thanks, Thorsten